# Bundle Error Installing CLD, macOS Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-sierra

I have been having some problems with `bundle install` since updating my OS to Sierra. The latest one is related with the gem cld:

```
Installing cld 0.7.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/private/var/folders/zn/wqrzmg6d4nq55m38xmpfyyn80000gn/T/bundler20161018-17743-2nngwicld-0.7.0/gems/cld-0.7.0/ext/cld
/Users/seque1990/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161018-17743-1l1g1xa.rb
extconf.rb
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... build_aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin16.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin16.0.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for style of include used by make... none
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

Makefile not found

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/folders/zn/wqrzmg6d4nq55m38xmpfyyn80000gn/T/bundler20161018-17743-2nngwicld-0.7.0/gems/cld-0.7.0
for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/zn/wqrzmg6d4nq55m38xmpfyyn80000gn/T/bundler20161018-17743-2nngwicld-0.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/cld-0.7.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing cld (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install cld -v '0.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

What is the best approach to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The cld project hasn't been touched in four years... You might have some luck rolling back your Ruby version, but if I were in your shoes, I'd be looking for alternatives to cld. In the meantime, you might try making sure your homebrew and xcode tools installation are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

As @MarsAtomico suggested I did update xcode and homebrew and was able to install the gem.